# query DISTINCT in Script DB

Tags: google-apps-script

Is it possible to fetch the records similar to [DISTINCT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp).
I have created a scriptDB form spreadsheet containing all the Employee Names and Manager names. I Need to get all the Manager names. But the things is manager column do have duplicates because multiple emp's have same manager.

How do I get this?

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in that extracts parts of objects from ScriptDB, but here's a function that will return an array of unique manager names. (I've made a guess at your data structure, adjust as necessary.)

```
function distinctManagers() {
  var db = ScriptDb.getMyDb();
  // Get employeers sorted by manager.
  var results = db.query({type: 'employee'}).sortBy('manager', db.LEXICAL);
  var distinctManagers = [];
  while (results.hasNext()) {
    var item = results.next();
    if (distinctManagers.length == 0 || item.manager !== distinctManagers[distinctManagers.length-1]) {
      distinctManagers.push(item.manager);
    }
  }
  debugger;
  return distinctManagers;
}
```

Comment: Yes i am doing something similar to this right now. `var managerList = sheet.getRange('B:B').getValues();` and then eliminating the duplicates, and running a ScriptDb query with each manager name. The problem is I have a spreadsheet with ~3000Rows and ~20Cols full of data. So I feel like this a bit time consuming and so checking if we have a way to do that directly from ScriptDb.

Answer (score 0):

Although the question was specific about using script, I'll add a second answer that avoids script altogether. You can extract the information in the spreadsheet using [built-in spreadsheet functions](https://support.google.com/drive/bin/static.py?hl=en&topic=25273&page=table.cs).

Assuming that your spreadsheet consists of Employee names in column A and Manager names in column B, here are some functions that will produce a list of unique manager names:

- `=unique(B2:B)` produces a column of names, in the order they first appear, excluding the column heading. Use range `B:B` to include the heading. Note that a blank name may appear, since the range expression includes everything in column B.
- `=sort(unique(B2:B))` as above, sorted.
- `=query(A:B, ʺselect count(A) where A != '' pivot Bʺ,true)` presents a table of the number of employees for each manager, sorted.
- `=transpose(query(A:B, ʺselect count(A) where A != '' pivot Bʺ,true))` is the same as the previous, except the manager names appear in the first column.
- `=filter(transpose(query(A:B, ʺselect count(A) where A != '' pivot Bʺ,true)),{true,false})` further refines the query to include *only* the manager names. Looks just like the `sort(unique())` example. One difference: this doesn't yield a *blank* manager name; `unique()` does.

The advantage to using one of the above formulas is that they will automatically recalculate when information on your sheet changes.

Comment: This doesn't help me in current problem as I have a dependency on scriptDb for sure, BUT I can definitely use in another spreadsheet for sure. Thanks for explaining the formulas.